# ¿Se puede dar formato en CMD a una ruta cuyo nombre contiene espacios en blanco?

Tags: c#, .net, string, cmd

El problema es que necesito ejecutar un comando en CMD, pero como las rutas de los archivos que busco en Windows contienen espacios en blanco, el mismo me exige usar comillas dobles (" ") para separar la rutas.

Cuando lo llamo desde C# intento "escapar" las rutas para incrustar la doble comilla, intentando con `@" "ruta" "` y `" \"ruta\" "`. Pero resulta que la cadena final arrastra la diagonal `\"ruta\"` y es incorrecto para el interprete de CMD.

¿Puedo decirle a CMD que busque las rutas sin usar comillas dobles o de qué forma puedo darle formato a la ruta para el comando que preparo para enviar desde C#?

El comando a ejecutar es parecido a:

```
C:/Users/user/Documents/Sistema de Calidad/OfficeToPDF.exe 
C:/Users/user/Documents/Sistema de Calidad/ + archivoEntrada
C:/Users/user/Documents/Sistema de Calidad/ + archivoSalida
```

Cabe mencionar que no puedo renombrar las carpetas, porque el proyecto está muy avanzado y si lo soluciono localmente funcionará también en el servidor de producción cuyas carpetas también tienen espacios en sus nombres.

Actualización:

El código que dejé como tentativo es el siguiente.

```
string consulta = @"""C:/Users/user/Documents/Sistema de Calidad/bin/OfficeToPDF.exe"" " +
                                          @" ""C:/Users/user/Documents/Sistema de Calidad/" + ruta + @""" " +
                                          @" ""C:/Users/user/Documents/Sistema de Calidad/" + rutaSalida + @""" ";

EjecutarComando(consulta);
```

y Ejecutar comando contiene:

```
 private void EjecutarComando(string comando)
        {
            try
            {
                var proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "cmd.exe",
                        Arguments = "/c " + comando,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    }
                };
                proc.Start();
                while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Vamos a ver, puedes postear tu codigo?

Comment: me parece que tu problema es que le estas pasando la arroba adelante al string. postea el codigo con el que construyes el string.

Comment: Necesitamos ver el código con el que montas la ruta, para ver que estás haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que tienes tus archivos bajo la misma carpeta puedes modificar la variable CurrentDirectory para que apunte hacia alli y asi no tienes que usar ni siquiera la ruta completa. Así sería el código:

```
string archivo1 = "...."; //Parámetro 1
string archivo2 = "...."; //Parámetro 2
string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
currentDir = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Sistema de Calidad\";
//Creo un nuevo proceso desde el cual voy a ejecutar el comando del cmd
Process p = new Process();
//Asigno la información de lo que voy a ejecutar, en este caso es la app y sus parámetros
//Agregué las comillas en caso de que el archivo contenga espacios
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("OfficeToPDF.exe", string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", archivo1, archivo2));
p.Start();
//Reestablezco el valor de la variable CurrentDir
Environment.CurrentDirectory = currentDir;
```